# How to deprioritize sign in the following addition rules?

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4

I have a grammar that allows numbers such as:

```
2
+2.5
-2.7
```

And various other forms. However, when it comes to lexing, when I have something like `2+2.5`, it seems to be picking it up as two tokens (instead) of three and categorizing it as:

```
`2` -- number
`+2.5` -- number
```

How would I resolve this ambiguity? Here is the relevant stuff I have so far:

```
parser grammar DBParser;
options { tokenVocab = DBLexer;}

root
    : selectStatement? (SEMI selectStatement)* SEMI EOF?    // for testing only
    ;

selectStatement
    : SELECT selectItem (COMMA selectItem)* COMMA?
    ;

selectItem
    : expr (AS? IDENTIFIER)?
    ;

expr
    : atom
    | atom PLUS expr
    ;

atom
    : NUMBER
    | STRING
    ;
```

```
parser grammar BParser;
options { tokenVocab = DBLexer;}

root
    : selectStatement? (SEMI selectStatement)* SEMI EOF?    // for testing only
    ;

selectStatement
    : SELECT selectItem (COMMA selectItem)* COMMA?
    ;

selectItem
    : expr (AS? IDENTIFIER)?
    ;

expr
    : atom
    | atom PLUS expr
    ;

atom
    : NUMBER
    | STRING
    ;
```

And input for testing:

```
SELECT 1;
SELECT 1+2;
SELECT +3, -2;
SELECT 'hello' AS word;
SELECT 'hello' word;
SELECT 'hello' word, 1, 3,;
```

How would I make the binary `+` operator have precedence over a number with an optional sign (which is longer?)

[image]

---

**Update:** maybe the answer is just to not pick up the sign in the number itself but to push that as a unary or binary operator as part of the expression?

Comment: Don't include the sign in the NUMBER token. It should almost always be an independent token. (And my advice is to avoid creating languages in which `-2` and `- 2` mean different things.)

Answer (score 0):

If you include the `+`/`-` in your Lexer rule for your number, then the Lexer *will* include it in your `NUMBER` token (it always attempts to match the longest sequence of characters that match any token rule).

You *could* require whitespace between operands and operators, but that wouldn't feel very unfriendly.

You'll have to account for signs in parser rules,

so something like:

```
expr: expr ('*'|'/') expr
    | expr ('+'|'-') expr
    | number
    | ID
    ;

number: ('-'|'+')? NUMBER;

NUMBER: [0-9]+('.'[0-9]+)?;
```

Comment: Or include the operator in an unary variant of the `expr` production: `expr: ('-'|'+') expr | ... | expr ('*'|'/') expr | ...`. That way, `-foo` will also be valid.